# PCD files into cloud of points

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

after scanning I have 2 kind of files -  some .pcd files and one with .xml extension that is keeping informations about places where .pcd was taken. ROS environment is set up on my workstation (Kinect). Could you give me some hints what should be next steps if I want to get Cloud Point? What i find out is that i should install some PC libraries? Some links may be helpfull as well.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263649/pcd-files-into-cloud-of-points/) by [RafMil](https://answers.ros.org/users/30506/rafmil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your have installed ROS desktop successfully, you don't need to install PCL separately. You will notice that a package named pcl_ros is already installed on your computer. Reffering [this link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) you can see that you can load a PCD file and then publish it on a topic in the following dummy code:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

...

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }

  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 1);
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud, output);
  pub.publish (output);

...
```

---

Originally posted by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) with karma: 161 on 2017-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-12**:
Or just use `rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud <file.pcd> [ <interval> ]` (from [wiki/pcl_ros - pcd_to_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pcd_to_pointcloud)).

**Comment by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) on 2017-06-12**:
Nice! This seems useful too.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-04-30**:
@Zubin Priyansh or @gvdhoorn, Can you please suggest same code for python?